# Regular expression for negative matching of string

Tags: regex, negation

x-env-sender: test@testing.com

This is my test string, I want to check all the addresses which are not with the domain testing.com

Below is my regular expressions:
^(x-env-sender:[^@]+@(?!testing.com$)[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4})

Any problem with this ? I am not able to get the required result.

Comment: how your test string looks like?

Comment: How about something like this: `^x-env-sender:\s?([^@]+)@(?!testing\.com)(.*)$` Which doesnt match "x-env-sender: test@testing.com" but does match "x-env-sender: test@foo.com"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex that will ensure your string does not end in `testing.com`:

```
^(x-env-sender:[^@]+@(?!testing\.com$)[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})$
```

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/zI9wB9/2).

I escaped the dot, as in your regex it is unescaped and can match any character.